# How to perform a scatterplot for cluster with drill in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, cluster-analysis, scatter-plot, hierarchical-data

With my data I did a cluster analysis for hierarchical data, now I would like to display the results interactively. I would like to perform with R a chart like the one below:

[image]
Where A, B, C, and D represent my 4 clusters based on the two variables of interest.

I would like to be able to create a R graph that when I click on a data contained in one of the 4 clusters, drill down on this data showing the children of each parent contained in that cluster.

I add an example of structure of my data:

```
PARENT
POINT   CLUSTER x   y
z1      A       10  5
z2      A       11  7
z3      A       12  9
z4      B       13  -2
z5      B       14  -4
z6      B       16  -6
z7      B       20  -8
z8      C       -5  2
z9      C       -9  4
z10     D       -1  -6
z11     D       -2  -3
z12     D       -3  -9 

CHILD
ID      SUB-CLUSTER x   y
z1      A           1   2
z1      A           2   3
z2      A           1   3
z2      A           2   1
z3      A           2   3
z3      A           2   4
z4      B           3   -2
z4      B           3   -4
z5      B           2   -1
z5      B           2   -6
z6      B           1   -5
z6      B           1   -9
z7      B           4   -7
z8      C           -1  1
z8      C           -1  2
z9      C           -2  3
z9      C           -3  3
z10     D           -4  -4
z10     D           -4  -5
z11     D           -2  -1
z11     D           -2  -5
z12     D           -8  -1
z12     D           -7  -1
```

Do you know if it is possible to build a chart of this kind in R or where could I find examples about it?

Any suggestions are appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hi Lorenzo, could we have some fake data as example of your dataset to do some tests? Hovever it could be useful look at `shiny` package to do those nice things.

Comment: hI @nhl I have update my question with an example of my data. I hope I have been clear enough, thanks!